# Script which copies original files from shortcut paths

Tags: windows, parsing, copy, directory, shortcut

I have a folder that has subfolders with some files that are shortcuts to their original file in a different location outside these main folder. I need to write a script (Windows preferably) that parses through each subfolder and goes to each folder from the shortcuts target path and copies the original file into a specific folder.

In the end I want a folder with a copy of all the original files that were shortcuts from my subfolders.

Is this possible?  Thank you so much!